# How to send a text file to a batch script with SendTO?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I added a bat file to my SendTo folder so I can right click on a text file and send it to the bat file. This works great.

However I want to simulate this via CMD commands in another bat file.

Tried this but doesn't work. What is the correct way of doing this?
Of course I have have done with with a direct path and that worked but I want to do it dynamically with SendTo.

```
start shell:SendTo/myBatch.bat "C:\Users\Work\Desktop\myfile.txt"
```

Comment: There is no easy way to get or invoke the sendto folder in a batch file. I'd suggest a wsh/batch hybrid.

Comment: The first thing you should note, is that you should not have any files in your SendTo directory, other than shortcuts. Put your batch file elsewhere in your file system, and create the shortcut to it in the SendTo directory instead. Then you would adjust the properties of that shortcut as/if needed.

Comment: Alternatively, and probably better in this case, create an Explorer context menu entry for .txt files, in the Windows registry, so that your end user can right click on a TXT file, and select the option to pass it as an argument to that batch file instead.

Comment: @Compo. Why not have a bat in the SendTo folder? It works fine for the right click menu. Is it a security risk or something?

Comment: Because, it was never designed for that @GaryCarlyleCook, there's no need to, and with the additional benefit of shortcuts allowing useful properties, why would you even consider it? Regardless, the context menu entry is better for your specific needs, and more easily achievable directly from your batch file.

Comment: @compo. Advice for other people is fair enough but my method for that works fine. Its trying to simulate it as a bat that is the issue.

Comment: But if you use the alternative idea I touted @GaryCarlyleCook, then you'd be able to do it directly from a batch file with built in tools, and without the need to seek the assistance of an alternative scripting language. This area is for comments, I've told you what I believe are the correct ways of doing it, which was your specific question, if you don't like it, that's fine, but nothing I've told you is incorrect, so why argue about it? Is it getting you any closer to a robust, efficient, or working, solution to your task?

Comment: @Compo. I appreciate the comments and advice. May end up doing it that way. Still, would be nice for somebody to give a direct answer to my question out of interest (If possible).